# Unable to clone bare repository with Git

Tags: linux, git

I've created a bare repository on an external hard disk in path

```
/media/Segate/Repos/project01.git
```

Then I've added and commit the latest version of my project sources to this repository.

Then I created another repository on my local hard disk in the path

```
/mc2012/mylocalrepos/project01
```

Now I am trying to get a working copy from the 'bare' repository, so I navigated to the local repo and tried to execute the following command:

```
$git clone /media/Segate/Repos/project01.git
```

but it is not recognizing the path, even though I am 100% positive it is there :( So can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong here? And how I can get a full working copy from the bare repo to put it in the local repo?

Error I get for $git clone /media/Segate/Repos/project01.git is 'Too many parameters'

Here is all the commands I executed: 
In `/media/Segate/Repos/project01.git`

```
$git init --bare
```

Then I went to the source folder and from within this folder I executed:

```
git init 
git add . 
git commit -m 'first commit' 
git remote add origin /media/Segate/Repos/project01.git 
git push --all
```

Then I went to an EMPTY folder `/mc2012/mylocalrepos/project01` and tried to clone by typing the command

$git clone /media/Segate/Repos/project01.git

but it game me an error 'Too many parameters'

Comment: you shouldnt create the local repo before cloning, cloning will create it.

Comment: Make sure you called `git init` in your primary repository, and have **not** already created your secondary repository (do **not** call `git init` on the second repository, as mentioned; `git clone` will do this for you).

Comment: Okay, folks, I've cleaned up the comments here. If you'd like to discuss, please use [chat] instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the "git add .", "git commit ..." dance, you stashed the files away in the same directory where you have the source. Nothing ever made it to the bare repo.